# New Zealand citizen returning to N.Z. after long stay away

Tags: residency, passports, new-zealand-citizens

I'm a N.Z. born citizen that has been living overseas for the last 30 years. Left there at 27 yrs of age.

My question is, once I renew my N.Z.passport, can I just roll up to N.Z. and live there again? Of course there will be the pension plan question, but I think that ought to be sorted due to having one from where I live now (Switzerland).

I ask, as I think I once read it would involve quite a lot of paperwork, but that was some time ago and now I can't find anything relevant to my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you renew your NZ passport, you may enter NZ and live there with no further paperwork required.

Based on what you've said about your age, you would be eligible for [New Zealand Superannuation](https://www.workandincome.govt.nz/eligibility/seniors/superannuation/superannuation-overview.html) at age 65 (since you lived in NZ for 7 years already after age 20, and you need 10 years before age 65). That's the current rules - note that there are [proposed changes to NZ Super](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=11812931) which would affect your eligibility if the rules are changed:

> In another major policy change, immigrants will have to live in New Zealand for twice as long - 20 years - to get access to NZ Super, including five years after they turn 50. It would apply as soon as the law changed - next year if National remains in power.

For your Swiss pension, New Zealand [does not have a Social Security Agreement with Switzerland](https://www.workandincome.govt.nz/pensions/travelling-or-moving/social-security-agreements/index.html). You will probably need to contact a financial professional (or Work and Income directly) to find out more about your individual circumstances.

Anyway, as always with moving countries, there will be a bunch of work involved in moving your finances and belongings from one country to another. However, once you have your NZ passport then there will be no further work from an immigration perspective.

Comment: Many thanks Greg, it almost sounds too easy, maybe it is though, heres hoping. I knew that about the swiss/NZ lack of agreement, so all accounted for on that side. Just seems a bit weird to just walk back in as if I never went or something, will report back should it be any different. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just be aware that NZ will deduct any overseas pensions from NZ Super when no social security agreement is in place between NZ and the overseas countries you are entitled to draw a pension.
If your overseas pension is greater than NZ Super, you don't get any NZ Super. If you don't get NZ Super, there are other things you don't qualify for, for example Winter Warmer payments. Not sure about Gold card, etc.
In return, if a NZer leaves NZ before pension age 65, they leave all of NZ Super behind and lose the lot.
Welcome to the country of government proclaimed "kindness". Immigrants, emigrants, beware.